# Create administrator rights in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have wanted to ask. I have a table tlogin. user_nm the first field and second field pass. so when the login form, if I login as admin then there is a special menu for admin.

how to manage it? please help

ow....ya, I using access for database

Thx b4

Comment: Do you mean VBA? VBA is native to Access, that is, you create macros in Access itself. VB.Net is a different thing altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you'd use a flag or secondary table related to each user to indicate what "rights" the user has. For instance, if using bit flags, you might have an extra field in your user table called IsAdmin, which would contain true if it's an administrative user, false if not.

Then, once the user has logged in and you've validated the password, you can check the IsAdmin field, and if true, allow them access to the appropriate functions.

that's a simplistic method but it would work. You normally WOULD NOT want to base rights solely on the user's name.

Comment: can give me some examples ? please